# Hangman code stuck on three different problems

Tags: java, arrays, stream

I'm trying to make a hangman game. On each turn, the user guesses a letter. If they guessed correctly, they can guess again. Otherwise, their remaining available guesses drops by one, and the guessed letter is put into an array.

When the user hits zero remaining guesses, the program is supposed to ask if they want to play again. If they answer yes, it is supposed to restart the game, and if they answer no, the program ends.

The problem I'm having is with the array that holds the guesses, and with restarting the game.

Also, the program will error every once in a while when starting. The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Hangman1.main(Hangman1.java:27)

The error when trying to restart the game is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Hangman1.main(Hangman1.java:101)

`searchArray` is the method that is supposed to take the position of the char array and copy that in asterisk array and return asterisk array, that doesn't seem to work. Running debug it seems the problem that causes the program to crash is that word will sometimes end up null, but only sometimes and I don't really know why

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Hangman1 {

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final int MAXSIZE = 15000;
    public static final int NUM_GUESS = 8;
    public static final int WORD_LENGTH = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int random = pickrandom(MAXSIZE); 

        try {
            // Set up connection to the input file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));

            instructions();
            keyboard.nextLine(); 
            clearScreen();

            String word = randomWord(input, random);

            System.out.println(word);
            String[] charArray = word.split("");

            System.out.print("\n");
            String[] asterisk = asteriskLine(word);

            String decision = "Y"; 
            //decision = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            System.out.println("Word to guess :");
            for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++) { 
                System.out.print(asterisk[count]); 
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

            int tries = NUM_GUESS; 

            System.out.println("Enter a letter to guess or 9 to quit");
            String guess = keyboard.next();
            String[] wrongGuesses = new String [NUM_GUESS];

            int guessMade = 0;
            do {
                //System.out.println(tries); 
                while (!(guess.equals("9")) && !(guess.equals(word))  && (tries > 0))
                {
                    String letter = guess.substring(0,1); 

                    if (word.indexOf(letter) < 0) {
                        clearScreen();

                        tries--;

                        wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses(guessMade, wrongGuesses, letter);

                        printArray(asterisk, charArray, word, tries, wrongGuesses, guessMade);
                        guessMade++;
                        guess = keyboard.next();
                    }
                    else {  
                        clearScreen();
                        asterisk = searchArray(charArray, asterisk, guessMade, letter, word);
                        printArray(asterisk, charArray, word, tries, wrongGuesses, guessMade); 
                        guess = keyboard.next();
                    }

                    if (charArray == asterisk) {
                        System.out.println("You won!");
                    }

                    if (tries == 0) {
                        System.out.println("You have no more guesses left"); 
                    }

                }
                if (guess.equals("9")) {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                }

                System.out.println("Play again? Y/N");

                decision = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();
                if (decision.equals("Y")) {
                    random = pickrandom(MAXSIZE);
                    word = randomWord(input, random);
                    charArray = word.split("");

                    System.out.print("\n");
                    asterisk = asteriskLine(word);
                    guess = keyboard.next();
                }


            } while (decision.equals("Y"));
            //System.out.println("Play again? Y/N");
            //decision = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
        }
    }

    //Clears screen after introduction 
    private static void clearScreen() {
        for (int blanks = 0; blanks < 80; blanks++) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // This method returns a randomly selected integer
    // between 0 and count-1
    public static int pickrandom(int count) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        return generator.nextInt(count);
    }

    // Places asterisks in place of the letters in the word
    // Parameter is the string word. it holds mystery word

    public static String[] asteriskLine(String word) {
        int i;
        String[] asteriskArray = new String [word.length()];
        for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

            asteriskArray[i] = "* ";
        }
        return asteriskArray;
    }

    public static void instructions() {
        System.out.println("              H A N G M A N. "
            + "\n This is a word guessing game. "
            + "\n A word will be selected at random and kept hidden. You will try to figure out the secret word by"
            + "\n guessing letters which you think are in the word. "
            + "\n You will guess one letter at a time. "
            + "\n If the letter you guess is correct, the position(s) of the letter in the secret word will be shown. "
            + "\n You will be allowed "
            + NUM_GUESS
            + " wrong guesses  If you guess incorrectly "
            + NUM_GUESS
            + " times, you lose the game. "
            + "\n If you guess all of the letters in the word, you win."
            + "\n\n Press enter to continue ");
    }

    public static String randomWord(Scanner input, int random) {
        String[] dictionaryWords = new String [MAXSIZE];
        int usedsize = 0;
        while (usedsize < MAXSIZE && input.hasNextLine()) {
            dictionaryWords[usedsize] = input.nextLine();
            usedsize++; 
        }

        String word = dictionaryWords[random];
        return word;
    }

    //Replaces correct guess in blanks 
    public static String correctWord(String guess, String word, String asterisk, char letter) { 
        return null;
    }

    public static void printArray(String[] asterisk, String[] charArray, String word, int tries, String[] wrongGuesses, int guessMade) {
        System.out.println("Word to guess");
        for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++) { 
            System.out.print(asterisk[count]); 
        }

        System.out.println("\nGuesses remaining: " + tries);

        System.out.print("Incorrect letters tried: ");
        for (int count = 0; count <= guessMade; count++) { 
            System.out.print(wrongGuesses[count] + " "); 
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnter a letter to guess or 9 to quit");

    }

    public static String[] wrongGuesses(int guessMade, String [] wrongGuesses, String letter) {
        wrongGuesses[guessMade] = letter;
        return wrongGuesses;
    }

    public static String[] searchArray(String[] charArray, String[] asterisk, int guessMade, String letter, String word) {
        int[] a = new int[word.length()];
        for (int count = 0; count < word.length(); count++) { 
            if (letter == charArray[count]) {
                asterisk[count] = charArray[count]; 
            }
        }
        return asterisk;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you've done a little searching on solving a NullPointerException (NPE), then you'll know that the most important bit of information that we need is the exception's associated stacktrace and some identification of the exact line that causes it, something that the stacktrace will tell you. Please post this information so that we can help you.

Comment: Why is this so important? The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same. **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me. In the future, please search on the subject before posting, since this is too common a problem to post yet another NPE question.

Comment: I put that at the end up the post saying that word becomes null, and I'm a beginner so I'm not really sure what the stacktrace is but the error says line 27. I was told that its because I pick a random number in the range [0, MAXSIZE), but there may be less than MAXSIZE words in the array, but not how to fix it and that wasn't my only problem

Comment: Post the **actual** stacktrace, the **full** text of the error message please.

Comment: This Is all that pops up when it errors out , this is for the error out when the user hits Y to restart the game                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Hangman1.main(Hangman1.java:101)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to do is to read all of your words in once and only once, and store them all into an ArrayList. Your current code tries to re-use a Scanner object that is already spent, and that will fail. Instead get your random word from the `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: I have to use the randomGenerator for the program for my class. Mostly everything I'm doing is pretty much how the teacher explained how to do it(beginner) so the deeper things go the more confused I'm getting

Comment: @SillyRabbit-3: sure, use a random generator, but do so with one that uses an `ArrayList<String>`, one created when the program starts. Otherwise you'll either have repeated NPE's or will need to re-read the File from scratch over and over.

Comment: I have to use that method specifically is where I'm getting at I can't change it. If you have a idea of how to fix it after the random generator method that'd be dope

Answer (score 0):

> Running debug it seems the problem that causes the program to crash is
>   that word will sometimes end up null, but only sometimes and I don't
>   really know why

```
 public static String randomWord(Scanner input, int random) {
        String[] dictionaryWords = new String [MAXSIZE];
        int usedsize = 0;
        while (usedsize < MAXSIZE && input.hasNextLine()) {
            dictionaryWords[usedsize] = input.nextLine();
            usedsize++; 
        }

        String word = dictionaryWords[random];
        return word;
    }
```

Sometimes `random` will be bigger than `usedsize`. 
So you need to move this line from outside the loop

```
 int random = pickrandom(MAXSIZE);
```

into this function, and have the maximum be usedsize (or usedsize-1).

You can protect yourself against this error, and work out whether you should be using usedsize or usedsize-1, by writing a unit test. Look into a Junit tutorial.

In your junit test, call randomword and pass it a very high value for random. Then

```
assert(word!= null)
```

Word is null when random is longer than the length of your dictionary.